# how to pass a number of items in an ant-design table

Tags: angular

Here's a library sandbox with the component I'm trying to use.

https://codesandbox.io/s/7vm68?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

I want to pass a total number of items to the table, so that it rendered the right number of pages. This `nz-table` component has a special prop `nzTotal` and I believe that's what I need but when I set it to , say, 5000, it still renders one page.

Here's the code from the library:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
interface ItemData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: string;
  address: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-table-edit-cell',
  template: `
    <button nz-button (click)="addRow()" nzType="primary">Add</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <nz-table #editRowTable nzBordered [nzData]="listOfData">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th nzWidth="30%">Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of editRowTable.data" class="editable-row">
          <td>
            <div class="editable-cell" [hidden]="editId === data.id" (click)="startEdit(data.id)">
              {{ data.name }}
            </div>
            <input [hidden]="editId !== data.id" type="text" nz-input [(ngModel)]="data.name" (blur)="stopEdit()" />
          </td>
          <td>{{ data.age }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.address }}</td>
          <td>
            <a nz-popconfirm nzPopconfirmTitle="Sure to delete?" (nzOnConfirm)="deleteRow(data.id)">Delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </nz-table>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .editable-cell {
        position: relative;
        padding: 5px 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .editable-row:hover .editable-cell {
        border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 4px 11px;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class NzDemoTableEditCellComponent implements OnInit {
  i = 0;
  editId: string | null = null;
  listOfData: ItemData[] = [];
  startEdit(id: string): void {
    this.editId = id;
  }
  stopEdit(): void {
    this.editId = null;
  }
  addRow(): void {
    this.listOfData = [
      ...this.listOfData,
      {
        id: `${this.i}`,
        name: `Edward King ${this.i}`,
        age: '32',
        address: `London, Park Lane no. ${this.i}`
      }
    ];
    this.i++;
  }
  deleteRow(id: string): void {
    this.listOfData = this.listOfData.filter(d => d.id !== id);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addRow();
    this.addRow();
  }
}
```

What's wrong with that pagination?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should use `[pageSize]` and `[pageIndex]` props too, when you use `[nzTotal]`